# Multiple testing, FDR and power

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, false-discovery-rate

Suppose that I've a data with a total of 30,000 observations. Each observation has a total of 6 values, 3 per condition. I'm interested in, let's say, testing if the means of these two conditions for each of these observations are different or not. For this, we typically apply a statistical test of choice to each of these 30K observations. In order to control the false positive rate due to multiple testing, we'd control for FDR at say 5% using BH method.

Example of an observation would be:

```
# dummy data
Condition 1: 40, 55, 48
Condition 2: 129, 77, 181
```

Also, let's assume I obtained a total of 1000 "significant" results. If I *filter* the data somehow, say, *remove all those observations where the maximum value across all 6 values is < 5* and end up with a filtered set of 20K observations, then I find that the number of significant results is a bit higher, say 1250. If I continue this approach of filtering data with higher and higher thresholds (< 10, < 20 ... preferably using quantile = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc..), I find that the number of significant results at 5% FDR keeps increasing up to a certain point and with *too stringent filtering* starts to reduce again.

It's fairly obvious that in controlling the FP in a multiple testing setup one compromises for the statistical power. My question is, are there methods that could somehow compute a filtering criteria which maximises the power (to detect after FDR correction)? If not, is it statistically sound approach to try and filter data with more than 1 value and decide on the one that maximises significance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying a filter to the data is clearly a case of selective inference (a.k.a. double dipping, data snooping, etc.)
If you are removing true null hypotheses, you will have an anti-conservative FDR.
If you are removing true alternative hypotheses, you will have a conservative FDR.

The filtering criterion you are using seems "fair" a-priori in the sense it does not seem to be correlated with the truthfulness of a hypothesis. 
On the other hand, the fact that you are making more and more discoveries suggests that high response values, might also be correlated with a difference between groups. I thus suspect your filtering step will have increased the FDR of the BH procedure. Try testing it using a simulation.

Also, could it be you are using an analysis that assumes homoscedasticity where the variances actually grow with the means?. If this is the case, try some non-parametric test to compare the groups.

Finally, back to the original question: I guess it should be possible to find the optimal number of hypotheses to test using the BH procedure. You will naturally need to define a generalized notion of power (say, average power over hypotheses). You will need to know the proportion of true null hypotheses and the power of each marginal test.

Comment: JohnRos, thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate on the line: "On the other hand, the fact that you're making more and more discoveries suggest that..."?

Comment: We assume that the counts follow a NB distribution. And yes, we assume homoscedasticity and with NB, var > mean. And variance is modeled as a quadratic function of mean. So, yes, variance increases with mean.

Comment: One more point: In [**this**](http://www.pnas.org/content/107/21/9546/F1.expansion.html) paper, in figure 1c, they show the effect of using 2 different filters at different thresholds (x-axis) against the number of NULL hypothesis rejected. And you see that the variance method (black lines), which is a better filter (acc. to this paper) rejects more NULL with increasing filtering.

Comment: "... you're making more and more discoveries...": A known phenomenon with FDR is that you can gain power by adding false null hypotheses, or removing true nulls [1] (referred to as "cheating with FDR"). This is not necessarily your case, just a suspicion of mine.

[1] Finner, Helmut, and M. Roters. “On the False Discovery Rate and Expected Type I Errors.” Biometrical Journal 43, no. 8 (2001): 985–1005. doi:10.1002/1521-4036(200112)43:8<985::AID-BIMJ985>3.0.CO;2-4.

Comment: I was unaware of that paper which makes an important point. I guess the problem now is to convince yourself that your filter is indeed independent of the testing statistic.

Comment: JohnRos, thank you for the reference. When you mean test it by simulation, do you mean test on simulated data or simulate it for different filtering thresholds?

Comment: yes indeed! That's what I was trying to do in a way with this question. I guess I could implement their weighted FDR approach as well (if only I can understand it) :).

Comment: By simulation I mean- apply your filter+BH procedure on simulated data to check that the FDR is controlled.